# Force shutdown receive on android

Tags: java, android

recently I shutdown Receiver

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"/>
```

but this is not get force shutdown.

perhaps have force shutdown receive on android?

and second question 
In string, what is OR operator?

I want

```
 if(action.equals("android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" || "android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF"))
```

but operator '||' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.string' error message.

thanks .

+add question.

```
    rebootProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "poweroff"});
```

this also force shutdown command?

Comment: what is your first question? You  added a shutdown receiver in your code and it is not receiving shut down event?

Comment: ACTION_SHUTDOWN is a system action so you can not send it to system if is not rooted phone

Comment: @GiapLee my phone is rooting phone

Comment: @sankyjain add in comment in your answer

Answer (score 0):

For second question answer

change

```
if(action.equals("android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" || "android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF"))
```

to

```
if((action.equals("android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN") || action.equals("android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF"))
```

For first one i didnot understand question

Comment: thanks, First question      for example.when I remove the battery.  this situation is force shutdown .    I want this situation (force shutdown) get receive

Comment: so you have created a broadcast receiver with android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN action and you are not able to receive it? This is your problem?

Comment: no  , android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN is normal shutdown.    this  well operation.   but force shutdown is not ACTION_SHUTDOWN